# programing a timer

Tags: pcb-design, programming, microprocessor

I am working on a hydroponic project that needs some programmable micro controller or something. Here is the deal. I am a mechanical engineer and my knowledge on electronics is pretty limited so here is the problem: there are three components that need to be controlled

1. pump
2. solenoid valve (please suggest which one to use ac or dc)
3. ultrasonic fogger

The pump pumps the water up to the tank for a certain time period, after that it shuts off. 15min after the pump has shut off the solenoid valve opens and drains the water from the tank. The solenoid valve then closes in 15min. 30min after the solenoid valve closes the ultrasonic fogger starts, the fogger runs in a 15min cycle for the next 3 hrs (in 1hr it runs for 15min), then after the 3hr are up the ultrasonic fogger shuts off and the pump starts and the cycle continues.

What I need basically is what all components will I need to build a device that will control this operation and also what program will i need to use to program the device.

I am really stuck on this and would appreciate any help

Comment: if you're a mechanical engineer you should understand flowrates.  Just figure out how much flow your system needs (probably governed by the fogger) and than match the pump and valve to it.  This is all basic on/off stuff.  Search for "mosfet arduino switch" and you'll be all set.  Make sure you put in the protective diodes and in-line resistors to avoid blowing up a microcontroller.  No one here is going to make your project for you.  Dirty hands are worthy hands.  Show your work and we'll help.

Comment: Please use proper English capitalisation in your writing to improve legibility (and appear smarter). A spell check wouldn't hurt either. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: Punctuation would be nice. I can't tell where your sentences are supposed to begin and end.

Comment: For a solenoid valve, use a sprinkler-valve. They run on 24 vac, so they are easy to power and control. And they support a lot of flow.

Comment: sorry for the grammar, on to the issue iam not controlling the flow but just the time for which a component is switched on and off i could achieve this by using three off the shelf timer but was hoping if i could do it using a single device or if any one of you can suggest me an off the shelf device that can achieve this please do so

Answer (score 1):

We don't do whole designs for you here.  As a mechanical engineer, you should understand there are different engineering disciplines, each with their own expertise you wouldn't expect the others to have.

The solution is to go hire a electrical engineer to design the electrical parts.  This really should have been obvious.